# Filtering results using Javascript and Django model not working

Tags: javascript, django, filtering

I have a model for events which are in different cities. When on the site you choose a city that you're in. What I want to do is that you only ever see available events of the city you're in. My problem is that in rendering the html results I seem to have a problem regarding the views and interaction between javascript in getting the city and the django models and having the results filter.

When I try to get the city stated within the view using 'GET' I keep getting an error regarding global variables not being declared that is I use this following construction. I've edited this construction to remove a declaration but I still get the same error:

```
def IndexPage(request):


    cityName = request.session['city-name']
    cityId = request.session['city-id']
    venues = ProfileVenue.objects.all().filter()
    oc_list = []

    for venue in venues:
        if Occurrence.objects.filter(date__gte=timezone.now()).filter(event__location=venue).exists() and venue.city.name==cityName:
```

or I get 'Key error' error with exception value 'city-name' if I use this construction:

```
if Occurrence.objects.filter(date__gte=timezone.now()).filter(event__location=venue).exists() and venue.city.name==request.session['city-name']:
```

So how would one go about making sure it filters correctly? I've looked around and I haven't yet found something suitable to my needs.

Javascript that sets city values

```
/* Ciudades */
if(localStorage.getItem("cities") == null){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/cities",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
    })
    .done(function(data, status){
        localStorage.setObject("cities", data);
    })
    .fail(function(data, status){
    });
}

$.each(localStorage.getObject("cities"), function(i, c){
    template = '<li><a href="" class="header-city-option" data-id="' + c.id + '" data-name="' + c.name + '">' + c.name + '</a></li>';

    $("#header-city-list").append(template);
});

if(localStorage.getItem("city-id") == null){
    localStorage.setItem("city-name", $("#header-city-list li:first-child a").data("name") );
    localStorage.setItem("city-id", $("#header-city-list li:first-childa a").data("id") );

`var token = $("input[name*='csrfmiddlewaretoken']")[0].val`ue;



        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "set-city-session",
            data: {
                cityName: city,
                cityId: id,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: getCookie('csrftoken')
            },
            success: function(){
                if(isClicked)
                    location.reload();

            }
        });
}

$("#header-city").html(localStorage.getItem("city-name") + ' <span class="caret"></span>');

$.each($(".city-filter-input") , function(i, v){
    $(v).val(localStorage.getItem("city-id"));

    changeHomepageByCity(localStorage.getItem("city-name"), localStorage.getItem("city-id"), false);
});

$(".header-city-option").click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();

    var city = $(this).data("name");
    var id = $(this).data("id");

    localStorage.setItem("city-name", city);
    localStorage.setItem("city-id", id);

    $("#header-city").html(city + ' <span class="caret"></span>');

    $.each( $(".city-filter-input") , function(i, v){
        $(v).val(id);
    });

    setCityInServer(city, id, true);
});

function changeHomepageByCity(city, id, isClicked){
    changeBackground(city);
    changeText(city);
    setCityInServer(city, id, isClicked);
}

function changeBackground(city){
    var urlBackground;

    switch(city){
        case "Manchester":
            urlBackground = "/static/img/fondo_main.jpg";
            break;
        case "Liverpool":
            urlBackground = "/static/img/liverpool_background.jpg";
            break;
    }

    $("#main").css("background-image", "url(" + urlBackground + ")");
}

function changeText(city){
    switch(city){
        case "Manchester":
            $("#main h2").html("Live the languages with Milingual in Manchester");
            $("#main p").html("We organize language conversation groups in the best venues in Manchester");
            break;
        case "Liverpool":
            $("#main h2").html("Live the languages with Milingual in Liverpool");
            $("#main p").html("We organize language conversation groups in the best venues in Liverpool");
            break;

    }
}

function setCityInServer(city, id, isClicked){
    var token = $("input[name*='csrfmiddlewaretoken']")[0].value;

    if(isClicked)
        location.reload();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "set-city-session",
        data: {
            cityName: city,
            cityId: id,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: getCookie('csrftoken')
        },
        success: function(){
            if(isClicked)
                location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

The Model for the venues

```
class ProfileVenue(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, blank = False, null = False, verbose_name = 'Creation Date')
    user = models.OneToOneField(app_settings.USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 250, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Name', unique = True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 5000, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Description')
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length = 12, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Phone Number')
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, verbose_name = 'City')
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 1000, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Address')
    participants_capacity = models.IntegerField( null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Participants Capacity')
    position = GeopositionField(null=True, blank = True,verbose_name='Position')
```

The Complete View currently working without filtering the City (shows all venues everywhere)

```
def IndexPage(request):

    venues = ProfileVenue.objects.all().filter()
    oc_list = []

    for venue in venues:
        if Occurrence.objects.filter(date__gte=timezone.now()).filter(event__location=venue).exists() and venue.city.name:#==cityName:  #request.session['city-name']:
            oc = Occurrence.objects.all().filter(date__gte=timezone.now()).filter(event__location=venue)[:1].get()
            oc_list.append(oc)
        if len(oc_list) == 3: break

    teachers = ProfileTeacher.objects.all().filter(published=True)[:3]
    teachers_list = []

    for teacher in teachers:
        if teacher.city.name: #== cityName: #request.session['city-name']:
            teachers_list.append(teacher)

    languages = Language.objects.all()
    levels = LanguageLevel.objects.all()
    events = EventType.objects.all()

    context = {
        'venues_today': oc_list,
        'teachers': teachers_list,
        'languages': languages,
        'levels': levels,
        'events': events
    }

    return render(request, "index.html", context)

def SetCitySession(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        request.session['city-name'] = request.POST['cityName']
        request.session['city-id'] = request.POST['cityId']

        return JsonResponse({})
def GetCitySession(request):
    if request.method == "GET":

        cityName = request.session['city-name']
        cityId = request.session['city-id']

        context = {
            "cityName": cityName,
            "cityId": cityId
        }

        return JsonResponse(context)


The html

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
        <div class="row">
            {% for venue in venues_today %}
                {% if venue.event.location.cover_image %}
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="venue {% if forloop.counter0 > 0 %}hidden-xs hidden-sm{% endif %}" data-href="{% url 'venue-page' venue.event.location.url %}">
                            <img src="{% if venue.event.location.cover_image %}{{ venue.event.location.cover_image.url }}{% else %}{% static 'img/default-venue.png' %}{% endif %}" class="venue-img">
                            <span class="venue-info">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><b>{{ venue.event.location.name }}</b></li>
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> {{ venue.event.location.address }}</li>
                                </ul>
                            </span>
                            <span class="venue-rating"><div class="content-rating" data-rating="{{ venue.event.location.rating }}"></div> <!--118 valoraciones--></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is this? def IndexPage(request): def GetCitySession(request):? I don't think you can declare a method inside another method, IndexPage should be a class

Comment: @alessioferri20 I realised that is why I commented it out. I left it there to show what I had tried.

Comment: request.session['city-name'] Is throwing a key error because there is no city-name in your session.

Comment: @kevswanberg the ['city-name'] is being set by the javascrpit under this function --> `function setCityInServer(city, id, isClicked)`  so I don't know it would not be there

Comment: That would send it in the request body and not the session

Comment: @kevswanberg so how would you change that?

Comment: I see you're setting the city in session on a different request, sorry I didn't see that before. Make sure the requests are happening in the order you expect, the session is getting saved, and persisted correctly.

Comment: @kevswanberg how would I ensure that? The requests, javascript and views are in different  files so I can't simply order by staggering them in written code. Additionally, the filtering is working on my local machine just fine. Its the AWS server version which is getting the key error

Comment: Using the browser network logging to ensure order and correctness in the requests. If it isn't working remotely it is likely a setting that is causing the session not to be read/saved correctly. Debugging on the server could require extra steps that depend on how you are running on AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for reference for anyone else, I ended resolving the key error issue by declaring it at the beginning of the view request. It worked fine from then on.

```
def IndexPage(request):

    if 'city-name' not in request.session:
        cityName='Madrid'
        request.session['city-name'] = request.POST.get('cityName')

    else:
        cityName = request.session['city-name']
    if 'city-id' not in request.session:
        cityId = 1
        request.session['city-id'] = request.POST.get('cityId')
    else:
        cityId = request.session['city-id']
```